# symfony3 - Showing 'This value is not valid' for choice type of dropdown that options adding via ajax

Tags: symfony

My scenario is,
I need to create a entity(module) with display order and the module is under a topic entity and association made correctly. On form load the topic dropdown and display order dropdown will be blank along the module name. When selecting topic the display order will fill with options via ajax/js. Display order will be 1 to a number that will be the total modules under the specific topic+1 . The upcoming display order will be selected automatically. And that's working perfectly. But my issue is about the display order validation after submit. Its saying 'This value is not valid'. I understands this is due to not giving 'choices' as array in form type, but this case i cant give as static in form type. Please help anyone knows a solution.
[image]

```
class ModuleType extends AbstractType {

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('topic', EntityType::class, [
                'class'         => 'AppBundle:Topic',
                'choice_label'  => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'Choose a Topic'
            ])
            ->add('name')
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('displayOrder', ChoiceType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr'     => ['class' => 'form-control button btn-sm nomargin']
            ])
    ;

}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Module'
    ));
}
```

}

Comment: I think that you should use FormEvent to  fill `displayOrder` with choices suitable for picked `topic` option. More info about Form Events in Symfony: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the Event Listener.

In your case for exemple:

```
// TopicType.php
private function addEventListener(FormBuilderInterface $builder)
 {
      // this function permit to valid values of topics
    $annonymFunction = function(FormInterface $form, $diplayOrder) {
        $entities = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')
                    ->getRepository('YourBundle:Topic')
                    ->findAll();
        if ($entities) {
            $topics = array();

            foreach($topics as $topic) {
                $topics[$topic->getName()] = $topic->getName();
            }    
        } 
        else $topics = null;

        $form->add('topic', EntityType::class, array(
            'attr' => array('class'   => 'topic'),
            'choices' => $topics));
    };

    $builder
        ->get('displayOrder')
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) use ($annonymFunction) {
                $annonymFunction($event->getForm()->getParent(), $event->getForm()->getData());
        });
}
```

Hope to help.

Comment: You cannot add children to a submitted form